# AWS Lambda Invocation Type "Event" Intermittently Takes A Long Time To Complete

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda

I am working on an application that requires a lot of calculations during every api call, and latency is a high priority. The application is built on AWS Lambda, API Gateway and DynamoDB, and we have put a great deal of effort to ensure we have provisioned all resources to handle our expected maximum loads (Provisioned Concurrency for Lamdba, WCU/RCU for DynamoDB, etc.).

This application also has some calculations that happen can happen in the background, and are not immediately required for the response values. Because of this, we have tried to split out these into asynchronous lambda function calls using `boto3` with an invocation type `Event`. We use the following code block for asynchronous calls, mostly to add more logging:

```
def invoke_async(fn, payload={}):
    log.debug(f"invoking {fn} asynchronously")
    try:
        lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName=fn, InvocationType='Event', Payload=json.dumps(payload))
    except Exception as e:
        log.error(e)
    log.debug("invocation complete.")
```

My understanding is that this should fire off the invoked lambda function and continue on with the code without waiting for a response. Normally, this seems to be the case and our api calls are finishing in <= 500 ms. However, we are intermittently getting large spikes in our latency, so that a request is taking ~ 60 seconds to complete:
[image: Lambda Called By API Gateway's Latency]

After looking at the CloudWatch Logs for one of these high latency calls, I see that a majority of the function takes <= 500 ms, while asynchronous call using the above block of code takes ~60 seconds to complete:
[image: CloudWatch Logs Showing High Latency Asynchronous Call]

As you can see, one line was logged at `2021-05-04T01:55:31.297Z`, and the next line was logged at `2021-05-04T01:56:31.393Z`, almost exactly 60 seconds later, and the only line of code of value between the two logged lines is `lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName=fn, InvocationType='Event', Payload=json.dumps(payload))` (refer to the code block above).

A few things I have checked:

- The payload body is only 4KB, so `json.dumps()` should not be taking a noticeable amount of time.
- The function called (`lambda-update-cache`) on average only takes <= 100ms, and there are no large spikes in latency for this function captured in CloudWatch.
- `lambda-update-cache` is not throttled and there doesn't appear to be any spillover cold starts.

Regardless of the above checks, I would expect `InvocationType=Event` to return very quickly, regardless of if the called function took a long time or had cold starts? Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: How long does your Lambda take to initialise? Those 60 second invocations might be down to a fresh Lambda being "spun up" and taking a long time to initialise. 60 seconds would be extremely long, but you did not provide any details on the init. Furthermore, if Latency is a high priority Python is probably not the right runtime to choose. I am working on tests across all Lambda runtimes and Python is one of the slowest with the highest request durations of all the runtimes. Go, .NET Core and Ruby are all a lot faster (about 2x). At least for average workloads.

Comment: You can set an SQS queue for your async calls. This way, you have no impact by the other slow lambda. You just have to send a message to the queue and subscribe your other lambda to this queue.

Comment: @Jens can I capture initialization time without having x-ray set up? The asynchronously invoked function only requires boto3 (not any large computational packages), so I would be very surprised if initialization took long at all. Even if initialization took a few seconds, would this cause `lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName=fn, InvocationType='Event', Payload=json.dumps(payload))` to hang until initialization was complete?

Answer (score 0):

"Lambda manages the function's asynchronous event queue and attempts to retry on errors. If the function returns an error, Lambda attempts to run it two more times, with a one-minute wait between the first two attempts, and two minutes between the second and third attempts. Function errors include errors returned by the function's code and errors returned by the function's runtime, such as timeouts."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html